Need to remove the gaps caused by different sizes of grid items in a grid layout
When I try to align these boxes with varied width and height, I can see empty spaces in both directions. I tried with flex and grid layouts and below is my output.
My output that has horizontal and vertical spaces in the layout
Below is the design mockup
This is the mockup of the UI that I am trying to build
Is there a techinique in grid/flexbox to achieve the layout given in the mockup?

Does this answer your question? CSS-only masonry layout

Yes, @SyndRain. I am unaware of the keyword 'masonry layout'. Thank you so much.

np, I agree it is hard to search without the keyword
